# Framework7 v5.7 Multiple pages in one view

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I'm a beginner with Framework7. In Framework7 there were "inline-pages", that allowed multiple pages to be declared in one view, and all of that could be included in one html file. Is there a similar way to do this with the latest version v5.7? Ref: https://v1.framework7.io/docs/pages-inline.html

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    ...
    <!-- Views -->
    <div class="views">
      <!-- View -->
      <div class="view view-main">
        <!-- Pages -->
        <div class="pages">
          <!-- Home page -->
          <div class="page" data-page="index">
            <div class="page-content">
              <p>Home page</p>
            </div>
          </div>
 
          <!-- About page -->
          <div class="page cached" data-page="about">
            <div class="page-content">
              <p>About page</p>
            </div>
          </div>
 
          <!-- Services page -->
          <div class="page cached" data-page="services">
            <div class="page-content">
              <p>Services page</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No...
But You can use multiply page in same view in latest Freamwork7 Version v4,v5 and v6.
best ref [Visit latest version f7 view resources](https://framework7.io/docs/view.html).
I am happy to help you. you can ask any here